# How to concatenate rows from 2 files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, loops, concatenation

I have 2 files:
nodes.txt

```
node1
node2
node3
```

descriptions.txt

```
Description1
Description2
Description3
```

How can I make a loop and get output as a concatenate rows of 2 files?

output.txt

```
node1 Description1
node2 Description2
node3 Description3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, this seems to be very common problem; so request you to please do use Search functionality of Stackoverflow where you can search the answers, BTW look for `paste` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
paste -d' ' nodes.txt descriptions.txt
```